# How to change my .android folder location to D drive instead of C:\Users\Jack

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

How to change my .android folder location to D drive instead of C:\Users\Jack? I tried editing my system environment variable to ANDROID_SDK_HOME to D:.android but this was not working in my case I am using Windows 10 Can anyone can help me to do that? I am using the latest version of android studio

Answer (score 1):

ANDROID_SDK_HOME is deprecated since Android Studio 4.2

Try changing `ANDROID_USER_HOME` environment variable to `D:\.android` `ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME` to `D:\.android` and `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` to `D:\.android\avd`

Update: Source of the information: [Android Environment Variables](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables)

Comment: my android sdk is there in e drive

Comment: Ah sorry, I mixed up Android Sdk and Android Sdk Home. I will update the answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).